# Is sum of dependent normal variables symmetric?

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

Consider two standard normal random variable, X and Y.

They both have mean 0, and variance 1. But we don't know their dependency. 
Is it possible for X+2Y to be nonsymmetric?

In another word, is it possible for P(X+2Y>0) = 1/2 to not hold.

I understand if they follow multivariate normal, the sum has to be normal and thus symmetric.

Is it possible to construct non-jointly Gaussians X and Y such that the equality does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - take $Y=-X$ if $X<0$ and $Y$ be "negative gaussian" independent of the value of $X$ if $X>0$. Then $X+2Y=-X>0$ for $X<0$ (i.e., $X+2Y$ is positive at least with probability 1/2); on the other hand, if $X>0$ and $Y<0$ they are conditionally independent, so that $X+2Y$ can also be positive with non-zero probability.